# meaning of multiple values in cache-control header

Tags: http, caching, browser-cache, cache-control, http-caching

I've read about single cache-control header value. To test what I learned, I opened facebook and inspect. This is the Cache-Control response header I get:

```
cache-control:private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
```

I am confused what this header actually tells, because it contains 4 values at once. So what happens with the resource send through the network, if it contains such header?

EDIT:

no-store says, "do not store at all, not in private not public caches", and no-cache says "yeees you can cache, but make sure you revalidate for freshness when resource is requested". Private says "you can store in the private caches". It cant do all 3 at the same time. But yet, here we are having them send in response at the same time. Looks like there are some additional rules I am not aware of.

Comment: Read the spec? https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7234.html#cache-response-directive

Comment: I know what they mean separate, I don't know what to think about them when there are more than one. no-cache and no-store mean different things and cannot be obeyed at the same time for example.

Comment: `no-cache` does not say “you can cache.” `private` does, and so it does contradict `no-store` in theory, but this not a problem in practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234) is a good reference for the precise meaning of the headers.

> no-cache and no-store mean different things and cannot be obeyed at the same time for example.

They absolutely can. The directives are redundant, but not contradictory. `no-cache`:

> indicates that a cache MUST NOT use
> a stored response to satisfy the request without successful
> validation on the origin server.

and `no-store`:

> indicates that a cache MUST NOT
> store any part of either this request or any response to it.

As `no-store` is essentially stricter than `no-cache`, the result is effectively `no-store`. Similarly for the other headers; I believe:

```
Cache-control: no-store
```

would be a simpler way to get the same result. However, it's possible that the header you're seeing is a combination of advice, rather than an intentionally consistent policy.

Note that, as [the spec says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.2.1), duplicated *directives* may be invalid:

> When there is more than one value present for a given directive
> (e.g., two Expires header fields, multiple Cache-Control: max-age
> directives), the directive's value is considered invalid.  Caches are
> encouraged to consider responses that have invalid freshness
> information to be stale.

but I don't believe that's the case here.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer. Private directive, indicates that the message can be stored in private caches, no-store instructs not to store in private nor public caches. What now? really confusing

Comment: Not quite; `private` indicates this "MUST NOT be stored by a shared cache." Again, no contradiction, but redundant.

Comment: Ah yes, I can see know. Thank you again.

Answer (score -1):

These are some good references: http://dev.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/    and     [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. I have read about them as individual. Now there are 4 of them and they exclude each other. For example, you cant obey no-store and no-cache at the same, since no-store says, "do not store at all", and no-cache says "yeees you can cache, but make sure you revalidate for freshnes when resource is requested". It cant do both at the same time. This is what bothers me.

Comment: @sanjihan You apply what is more strict.