# Cache-Control: are private and no-store mutually exclusive?

Tags: asp.net, web, web-config, cache-control

I wonder if I can set

```
<add name="Cache-Control" value="private, no-store"/>
```

Does it make sense? Or I have to choose one of them?

Thank you,

Dan

Comment: Check this [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#Examples)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [meaning of multiple values in cache-control header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501479/meaning-of-multiple-values-in-cache-control-header)